# Check user is in User Group / Custom User Permissions

Tags: templating, users, current-user

I'm trying to restrict access to items in a channel using some form of custom user permissions however I don't appear to be able to create or set custom read permissions for a channel using crafts permissions as they currently are, I'm therefore trying to do something using either user groups or custom fields on the user and validate if a user has access that way.

I'm hoping this is along the right lines, although it doesn't seem ideal, so is it possible to check if a user is in a certain user group elegantly using twig?

I can do `{{ if currentUser.admin }}` and I'm guessing I could therefore do something like `{{if 'groupnamewithaccess' in currentUser.groups }}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is ['isInGroup'](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#isInGroup)

```
{% if currentUser.isInGroup('groupHandle') %}
```

It will also accept an actual group object or a group ID as well.

There is also [getGroups](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#getGroups):

```
{{ currentUser.getGroups() }}
```

Will return an array of [UserGroupModels](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usergroupmodel) all of the groups the user belongs to.

And finally, [can](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#can):

```
{{ currentUser.can('permissionName') }}
```

Will check if the current user has the given permissions, whether that was indirectly assigned to them in a group, or directly assigned to them as a user.

Comment: This is perfect, isInGroup works perfectly.

Comment: Any chance that we can get something like this to work? Sometimes I just need to make sure that a user is NOT a member of a group. Right now I don't see a simple way to make this determination.

{% if !currentUser.isInGroup('groupHandle') %}

Comment: @DavidAaronMcInnis Use `{% if not currentUser.isInGroup('groupHandle') %}`

Comment: Can isInGroup be accessed from within a plugin?

Comment: @DavidAaronMcInnis `craft()->userGroups->getGroupsByUserId($user->id)`

Comment: I presume this is only about viewing the actual page for the entry rather than being able to restrict edit/creation by a user group?

Comment: You can also do `currentUser.isInGroup(['groupHandle1','groupHandle2'])` for an OR, which is pretty neat.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking to check groups and/or permissions from your plugin controller with PHP, you can access the same methods.

**Craft 3.0.x:**

```php
//get the current user from craft
$user = Craft::$app->getUser();

//check if the current user has permission to edit certain entries
$user->getIdentity()->can('editEntries: 27')

//check if user is in group
$user->getIdentity()->isInGroup('specialGroupHandle'));
```

**Craft 3.1.x**

Since Craft 3.1.x not uses ids to check permissions anymore but uids you need to pass the uid of your section

```php
$user->getIdentity()->can('editEntries: 86f6afac-1d8c-43ba-8624-12d925ba57f5')
```

**Craft 2:**

```php
//get the current user from craft
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();

//check if the current user has permission to edit certain entries
$checkPerms = $user->can('editEntries: 27');
```

$checkPerms will return a boolean

Comment: awsm - thx Robin and David

Comment: Just a note that it's probably more clear that "get the current user" should be `$user = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity();` as `Craft::$app->getUser()` technically returns the User service/component (as noted by Robin here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/25917/6275).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation:
I wanted to restrict some users from certain entries.

I've created a checkboxes field called "cf_userRights_checkboxes" where the label is the user-groups name and the value is the user-groups id. Then added that field to a section.

In a section entry you will be able to set the user-groups that have permission and then check if the currentUser is in one of these groups:

```
{% set condition = 0 %}
{% for userGroup in currentUser.getGroups %}
    {% if userGroup.id in entry.cf_userRights_checkboxes %}
        {% set condition = 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if condition %}
    please enter
{% else %}
    sorry, not you
{% endif %}
```

Note: you have to loop through user-groups because a user can be in more than one group.

Let me know if there's a better solution.

Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Like in answer before of Robin Schambach and David Rampersad I tried to solved it this way:

`$user->getIdentity()->can('editEntries: 86f6afac-1d8c-43ba-8624-12d925ba57f5')`

Anyway I had to remove the space between the uuid and the permission string:

`$user->getIdentity()->can('editEntries:86f6afac-1d8c-43ba-8624-12d925ba57f5')`

Inside my module I ended up with that:

`$user->checkPermission('editEntries:'.$entry->section->uid)`