# Restricting access to fields based on user group

Tags: field, entry, user-groups

I saw this thread [Check user is in User Group / Custom User Permissions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/check-user-is-in-user-group-custom-user-permissions) had an idea. Can I use USER group to limit who can see the Author dropdown on the entries form? Is this even permitted the craft license. I really need to remove that field from view of two user groups. Also would be nice to be able to limit which fields a user has access to when creating an entry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Control Panel User Group](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpusergroup) plugin to automatically add special classes to the `<body>` tag in the CP.

Once those classes are in place, it's easy to use [CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) or [JavaScript](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) to hide fields from certain user groups (or trigger other behavior based on user group status).

** Disclaimer: I'm the author of all of those plugins. :)*

Answer (score 1):

Both of those are on the to-do list. In the meantime your best bet would be to write a plugin that conditionally hides those fields via Javascript.

Comment: I went ahead and developed a user experience using frontend forms etc. I would recommend this to folks in my position. I locked down CP for admins only. Even my editorial staff is making use of frontend forms and custom plugins.