# How can i check an entry author's user group?

Tags: user-groups, author

I'm trying to check if a user is part of a user group but not having any success!
I tried this:

```
{% if entry.author.groups == 'authors' %}
```

But even though the user is definitely in a user group with that handle, the output inside that if statement doesn't show up.

I also tried this:

```
{% if entry.author.admin != 1 %}
```

That DID work, but unfortunately i don't just want to check if the user is not an admin, i want to specifically check their user group.

Comment: maybe you can find your answer here?
[questions/1087](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/check-user-is-in-user-group-custom-user-permissions)

Comment: Ah, spot on Fabio! I feel a bit foolish that i somehow missed the isInGroup method. My code now looks like this:
{% if entry.author.isInGroup('authors') %}
And works like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

As Fabio pointed out, i'd managed to miss the [isInGroup](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#isInGroup) method. Slightly embarrassing!

So for anyone else looking to do what i asked, i changed my code to the following:

```
{% if entry.author.isInGroup('authors') %}
```

and it works perfectly now.