# Getting info on the currently logged in user

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

Trying to get the currently logged in user's groups. Trying to get at that by using the user ID. I am currently testing as Admin - user number 1.

```
Craft::$app->getUser()->id
```

Returns a user ID (11) that does not exist in the Users table. The Users table has ID's of 1, 20, 21.

How do I get user ID or more specifically, the currently logged in user's groups?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Craft::$app->getUser()
```

returns only the user service/component. You should read the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-users.html) about that

What you want is the current Identity

```
Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()
```