# Else statement outputting three bits of content

Tags: users, current-user

I have implemented an if/else statement and when I add the information to the 'else' part it outputs three duplicates of the same content.

I am calling the if statement to check if the user is signed in here more andless.
If they are they will get a booking form which shows up fine and only one of them.

```
{% for user in craft.users.groups('nomad') %}
{% if user.isCurrent %}
<div class="wrapper">
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}

    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('studios').search(studio) %}
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[studioEmail]" value="{{ entry.email 
    }}">
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" 
    value="amForms/submissions/saveSubmission">
    <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="bookingForm">

    {# Optional: Redirect URL. Will redirect to current page by default. #}
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="booking-form/thank-you">

    {{ craft.amForms.displayAntispam() }}


            <div class="input__wrapper">
                <label for="fields-firstName" class="sr-only">First 
     Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fields-firstName" 
      name="fields[firstName]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="First Name" 
     value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}">
            </div>

            <div class="input__wrapper">
                <label for="fields-lastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fields-lastName" 
               name="fields[lastName]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Last 
               Name" value="{{ currentUser.lastName }}">
            </div>

            <div class="input__wrapper">
                <label for="fields-mobileNumber" class="sr-only">Mobile Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="fields-mobileNumber" name="fields[mobileNumber]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Mobile Number" value="{{ currentUser.mobileNumber }}">
            </div>

            <div class="input__wrapper">
                <label for="fields-startDate" class="sr-only">Start 
                Date</label>
                <input type="text" id="fields-startDate" 
                name="fields[startDate]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="start 
        Date">
            </div>

            <div class="input__wrapper">
                <label for="fields-endDate" class="sr-only">End Date</label>
                <input type="text" id="fields-endDate" name="fields[endDate]" 
                autocomplete="off" placeholder="End Date">
            </div>

            <div class="input__wrapper">
                <label for="fields-studio" class="sr-only">Studio</label>
                <select name="fields[studio]" id="fields-studio">
                    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('studios').find() %}
                        <option value="{{ entry.title }}"

                        {% if studio == entry.title %}
                                selected="selected"
                        {% endif %}


                        >{{ entry.title }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>



    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </div>
```

Then this is the else statement. I think I might need to add something to the     {% else %}. Though I don't see why it would be outputting three duplicates of the same content in the first place.

```
  {% else %}
  <section class="form__wrapper">
  <div class="content__form_wrapper sign-up_wrapper">
    <h1>Become a Digital Nomad and join the community</h1>
    <p>You need to be a member to rent a desk, it will only take a moment of   
    your and you will be on your way.</p>

    <a href="{{ siteUrl }}users/sign-up" class="">Sign Up</a
</div>
</section>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Maybe because there is a loop? It will output the content for each user in the group

Comment: Yea it seems to be pulling in for each 'user', will try to fix it now.. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Why do you even use this loop? It really makes no sense at all

Comment: To be honest I didn't even know this was a loop :/..  I am just trying to display a form if the user is logged in. If they are not it won't show and sign up button will instead.. I thought an if/else statement would be the way todo this?

Answer (score 1):

In Craft there are several so called [global variables](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/global-variables.html) one of them is the `currentUser` thus you can check if someone is logged in with

```
{% if currentUser %} 

{% else %} 

{% endif %}
```

You don't need to loop a user array

Comment: aaah ok can I still target a certain user from the 'users group' with this {% if currentUser in craft.users.groups('nomads') %} As I am pulling some information so the form is already populated

Comment: Please read this https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/check-user-is-in-user-group-custom-user-permissions