# Restrict access to Element API endpoint

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I'd like to Restrict access to Element API endpoint by the current user's group.

Is this possible Using Craft 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is you can see here [how to check permissions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/check-user-is-in-user-group-custom-user-permissions)

You can get the [current user](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/services/UserSessionService.html#getUser-detail) with

```
$currentUser = craft()->userSession-getUser();
```

Then you can check the same conditions like in the example link. If the conditions are false you can return an empty array instead of your endpoints

```
if(!$currentUser->isInGroup('groupHandle')) {
    return [];
}
```

Please make sure to check if the current user is not null

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Is there a way to throw an exception too, so that I can warn users who are not able to view the resource?

Comment: You'll need to throw the exception in your transformer function, however keep in mind exceptions won't be thrown in live mode so the user will be redirected to the homepage instead. The quick and dirty way would be to `die()` your script out with a message. The clean way would be to create a custom route for each api endpoint and display the message in your controller

Comment: `die('You cannot access this resource')` is exactly what I need for this. Thank you !!